# ANTLR3 operator with parameter

Tags: parameters, antlr, operator-keyword, antlr3

First, i know the title might sound a little bit weird, but I don't know how else to call it. If someone gets a better idea than me, please edit.

Now, the problem:

- I have a pretty old grammar and I need to addapt to a new request
- the old form looked like this:

  "first text" * "second text";

which is basically doing some text operation. It doesn't matter what. Let's just say it concatenates the text. This is generatting a pretty basic tree having the texts as leafs and the operator as root

- now, the new request is to 'parametrize' the concatenation operation by specifying the number of letters I need to concat. The new form should look like this:

  "first text" *(3) "second text";

meaning that it has to take first 3 chars from the `first text` and the first 3 chars from the `second text`

- also, the new grammar needs to be compatible also with older format (parameter/paranthesis are not mandatory)
- I have implemented a `CommonTreeAdaptor` class that for each node, generates an instance of my own class (`QNode`). Kind of a factory. I can add new properties to the object designated to handle the operator. Let's say it is `QNodeStar`.
- The grammar looks like the one below:

  grammar QGrammar;

  tokens {
      COMPUTEOP = '*';
      }

  ```
  ...
  ```

  public
  topexpr
    : expr SEMI -> ^(ROOT expr)
    ;

  expr
    : CRIT (COMPUTE^ CRIT)*
    ;

  fragment CRIT
    : '"' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+ '"'
    ;

  COMPUTE
    : (COMPUTEOP | COMPUTEOP LPAREN! INT RPAREN!)
    ;

Of course, it is more complex than this, just putting here something to give you an ideea on what I have.

So, my question is, how can I make 'dissapear' the INT parameter from COMPUTE definition and to automatically `move` it to the criteria node (`QNodeStar`) without having to change the tree layout and just from the grammar definition file?

**Update:** Examples on how I would like to get the trees:

**1:** "a" * "b"

```
    *
   / \
 "a" "b"
```

- this is how the tree looks like now. With this, things are pretty simple: values are always leaves;

**2:** "c" *(3) "d"?

```
    *
   / \
 "c" "d"
```

- I know the tree looks identical with the 'old one' (#1). I want it like this for 2 reasons: backward compatible (default value for parameter is 1) and I don't want to change the tree execution method only for this operator to avoid conditions like `if (node == 'star') traverse1() else traverse2()` while iterating nodes in the tree. I was thinking that there is some way - I couldn't identify yet - to 'eat' the parameter (`3`) and pass it as a value to `QNodeStar` object in the root in a similar way validation methods. I succeeded to make the tree look like the foolowing one, but this doesn't help me too much:

```
     *
   / | \
 "c" 3  "d"
```

Comment: Well, if I throw away the parameter (`3`), I will not be able to tell how to 'execute' the operator, right? Operator `*(3)` will be identical with operator `*` and there will be no gain there. The expression can be more complicated (Ex: `"a" *(1) ("c" *(7) "d");`), so I need to keep it somehow bound to the node.

Comment: Yes, I need to extend current functionality, the grammar it's pretty complex and I would like to be as much as possible consistent.